# How to get json response from internal api request in laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5.4

My route file (routes/api.php) :

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'cors', 'prefix'=>'v1/'], function(){
    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
    Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
    Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController');

    Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
    Route::get('authenticate/user', 'AuthenticateController@getAuthenticatedUser');
});
```

My ProductController file():

```
public function index(){
    $request = Request::create('api/v1/products/', 'GET');
    $instance = json_decode(Route::dispatch($request)->getContent());
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($instance); exit;

    return view('pages.users.my_sell', ['products'=>$products]); 
}
```

while i try to print the $instance variable i get the following error :
[image]

i need to get all the object from the api and need to pass the objects to my blade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, have you included this?

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong. If you do not want to repeat Eloquent code, just create a `getAllPproducts()` method in the model and use it in controller methods:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('pages.users.my_sell', [ 
        'products' => $this->product->getAllProducts()
    ]); 
}
```

Just an example of `getAllProducts()`:

```
public function getAllProducts()
{
    return $this->paginate(20);
}
```

Comment: i need to get the all products only from api because i will use that api in my mobile application too. so if i get the fields from the api then it would be easy to get it in the app.

Comment: @Mukil API is a part of the app, you still need to get data from the model and not try to create a different request call to the API.

Comment: i need to join two table and i transform the return json object as i need in my product API controller. i again need to join those tables in this product controller to get the object that i need. so i need to repeat the work twice.

Comment: @Mukil move all DB related logic to the model and use it in all controller methods you need. You may want to read about MVC pattern to understand how it works.

Comment: sure. but is there a way to make internal api request ?

Comment: Dude, you're understanding this wrong. You don't need to create another request, that's not how it works. You want to get the data in the same request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142159/discussion-between-mukil-and-alexey-mezenin).